# Issue in gzip compression

Tags: tomcat, compression, gzip

I am using gzip to compress the loading files. For that i have written the following code in server.xml in tomcat.

```
<Connector 
compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/json,text/javascript,text/css,text/plain,application/json,application/javascript"
compression="on"
compressionMinSize="2048"
connectionTimeout="200000"
noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
port="8080"
protocol="HTTP/1.1"
redirectPort="8443"/>
```

What i get is "Content-Encoding : gzip". But for some files it is not get compressed.I cant get where the problem is. Please some one help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the value of compression to "force".It works.

[For reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html)